# Make pattern match directories

Tags: directory, make, defaults, gnu-make

I'm using gnu make and stow to manage some configurations (dotfiles).
I have multiple directories in my repo:

```
dotfiles/
├── Makefile
├── package1/
└── package2/
```

Currently, my Makefile looks like:

```
PACKAGES = package1 package2

.PHONY: all $(PACKAGES)

all: $(PACKAGES)

package1:
    stow --no-fold $@

package2:
    stow --no-fold $@
```

I want to define a default rule for packages, so I did:

```
PACKAGES = package1 package2

.PHONY: all $(PACKAGES)

all: $(PACKAGES)

%:
    stow --no-fold $@
```

But that didn't work:

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
$ make package1
make: Nothing to be done for `package1'.
$ make package2
make: Nothing to be done for `package2'.
```

So: Is it possible to define a "default" rule for directories? If yes, how I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace your rule with:

```
$(PACKAGES):
    stow --no-fold $@
```

Comment: No, that's ok. It's equivalent to specifying identical rules for every member of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solved my issue.

Just for completeness, can I override a rule for a package (possibly without generating warnings)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Gilles. I removed the irrelevant sentence from my answer. @S1cK94: I could not find a way to override a rule without getting a warning, unfortunately.